# K-th largest element in BST

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find the K-th largest element in a Binary Search Tree using reverse inorder approach by using a counter. Here is what I have implemented:

```java
int klargest(Node root,int k,int count)
{
    if(root != null)
    {
        klargest(root.right,k,count);
            
        count++;
        if(count == k)
            return root.data;
            
        klargest(root.left,k,count);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

But the issue is that when count = k, the code does not return the answer to the caller function but instead to a sub-call. Due to this, the answer is lost. In other words, the recursion does not stop there and it keeps on going until all the nodes are visited. In the end, I get the answer -1. What I want is that the recursion should end when count = k and the required answer should be returned to the caller function. How can I do this?

**Note:** I neither want to use a global variable nor an iterative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you do not return your node - the recursive call results are ignored. Rewrite it so it returns a Node:

```
Node klargest(Node root,int k,int count)
{
    Node result = null;
    if(root != null)
    {
        result = klargest(root.right,k,count);
        if (result != null)
            return result;            

        count++;
        if(count == k)
            return root;
            
        result = klargest(root.left,k,count);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
int kthLargest(Node node, int k) {
    int rightCount = count(node.right);
    if (k <= rightCount) {
        return kthLargest(node.right, k);
    } else if (k == rightCount+1) {
        return node.data;
    } else {
        return kthLargest(node.left, k - rightCount + 1);
    }
}

int count(Node node) {
    if (node != null) {
        return count(node.left) + count(node.right) + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```